# Import cURL Command For Uploading Files Into Postman

Tags: curl, post, postman

I would like to convert following cURL into specific postman script, so that i can post request through postman.

```
/usr/bin/curl --request POST -F "files1=@image_0026.jpg" -F "files2=@image_0027.jpg" -F "files3=@image_0028.jpg" -F "files4=@image_0029.jpg" -F "files5=@image_0030.jpg" -F "files11=@image_0036.jpg" --header "ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   http://localhost:10001/api/reque
```

I did 'import' from postman which eventually converted into postman script but contentType got changed to 'form-data'.

The cURL is working but not able to make postman request for the same.

Suggestions needed. thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably trying to be smart as the `form-data` is the only place on the UI that you can attach a file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:10001/api/reque \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.aqilix.bootstrap.v1+json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F files1=@image_0026.jpg \
  -F files2=@image_0027.jpg \
  -F files3=@image_0028.jpg \
  -F files4=@image_0029.jpg \
  -F files5=@image_0030.jpg \
  -F files11=@image_0036.jpg
```

Comment: What did this change?