# Curl file upload issue

Tags: curl, postman

Curl command from Postman not working. HTTP request works through Postman.

> curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload'
>   --form 'file=@/C:/Users/documents/test.txt'

`iter.hasNext()` returns false instead of true.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed the `-F` option.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50312830/9225626) for example.

Comment: Doesn't work as well. I believe --form is the same as -F